# install printer on my Debian based NAS

Tags: debian, cups

I run Debian on my lokal NAS (zyxcel NSA 325) and want to install a printer (Epson Stylus SX 125) I not advanced in Linux and use my NAS only as a SAMBA storage.

I have installed CUPS and I think I need to install the drivers for my Stylus.

I found Linux Based drivers for my printer here:
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Here the drivers I get when I search my printer:

```
epson-inkjet-printer-n10-nx127-1.0.1-1lsb3.2.i486.rpm   1.7 MB  
epson-inkjet-printer-n10-nx127_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_i386.deb   1.7 MB  
epson-inkjet-printer-n10-nx127-1.0.1-1lsb3.2.x86_64.rpm 1.69 MB 
epson-inkjet-printer-n10-nx127_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb  1.68 MB 
epson-inkjet-printer-n10-nx127-1.0.1-1lsb3.2.src.rpm    2.24 MB
```

Which driver I have to use and how to download the Driver and install it?

My main target is to use my old printer via SAMBA. When I have installed my driver is my printer automatically reachable via SAMBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are binary-only drivers (the src.rpm includes precompiled .so files). They're for x86 and x86_64/AMD64 only. So they won't work on your ARM-based NAS.

However, according to [a post on the Raspberry Pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=93579), the Gutenprint  Stylus T22 driver will work.

Basic steps to install are:

1. `apt install printer-driver-gutenprint` (or however you prefer to install packages);
2. add your user (on the NAS) to the `lpadmin` group. On the command line: `adduser your-user-name lpadmin`.
3. use a CUPS admin tool or the CUPS web interface (`http://nas-ip-address:631/`—though I'm not sure if it allows remote access fresh out of the box, you may need to edit `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` or alternatively use SSH port forwarding so your connection comes from `localhost`; see below.)
4. Up top, click "Administration", then under "Printers", "Add Printer". You'll probably be asked for a login; your user name and password should work.
5. You should see your printer listed (at least if it's USB), select it. Proceed through the add printer screens.
6. When asked for the make, tell it Epson. For model (according to that forum post), pick "EPSON Stylus T22 - CUPS+Gutenprint". (You could also try some of the similar model numbers to SX125)
7. After it's added, go back to the administration tab, and there should be a checkbox "Share printers connected to this system"; check it. Then press "save settings".

**SSH Port Forwwarding** If it's needed, do something like `ssh -L1234:127.0.0.1:631 your-user@nas-ip-address`, and leave that session open. Then visit http://localhost:1234/ in your web browser.